# EBAS Issue : Helper Tool Integration issues

Tags: macos, vpn, helper, keychain, system-configuration

I am working on application in which i have to create and connect to VPN Server direct through my application.

After lots of research i came to know that i need to store Password and SharedSecretKey in **System.Keychain.** now to store PASSWORD and SHAREDSECRETKEY in SYSTEM Keychain we need helper tool as per apple's guideline.

Now i downloaded the [CODE](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html) from apple and tried to add my certificate and identifiers in sample code but it doesn't work for me.

Do i have to use 2 different identifier for app id and Helper Tool identifier?

Any one have any proper implementation steps for this?

Any help will be appriciated.